# PRESTASHOP: Automate shipments: how to insert the SENT object in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, prestashop

I need to change the order status using mysql commands

Let me explain, I created a PHP script that automatically generates shipping labels for paid orders and I automatically inserts the generated shipping number (from script) in table ps_orders (shipping number field).

For each order I have to go in the tab orders and modify it as shipped.

How can I automate this step?

I should tell to my script to "mark the order as shipped" by sql and PHP

now i have the following steps:

- PHP create shipping code
- PHP and MYSQL enter it in the field shipping_number

and the next must be......

- modify the item as shipped (by PHP and MYSQL)

I have seen that is also enhanced the delivery_number column and delivery_date but have not found the field "shipping State" ...

Thanks, I hope I was clear

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to update is current_state field in ps_orders DB table. Evaluates an int from ps_order_state_lang  DB table.